# html select tag used in iOS app, but the multiple select not works

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, select

In my ios app, I use loadHTMLString to show a view. In this view, I create a select tag with multiple selection. I use the html code:

```
[HTML appendFormat:@"<select multiple=\"multiple\" onchange=\"updateSurveyObject();\" name=\"%@\" id=\"%@-0\"  >",elementID,elementID];
```

[image]
When I click on one option, it will invoke web delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

But the question is: if I click on that option again or click on the second option, it won't call that delegate any more. Even click on Done button, the delegate method is not called.

So, how should I do with the multiple selection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the "onchange" to "onblur". It's not perfect but it works. Do you have better idea?thx